# error with last row in loop adding a row when there is not data in the row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am looking for a way to fix this loop where the system keeps adding a row of data that is not there, I have stared at this until I'm crosseyed, please advise where the issue is and what is required to fix it.

```
    ***Sub Autolist_INS_MO()
    'working sheets in BMAutoCalcs.xltm are AutoList, where it pulls in the list data,
    'Settings and Shed Settings, where it places the data for calculations respectively,
    'then at the end of the loop of each line, it will place the result data back at the end of the 
    line in AutoList.
    'it will do this twice once for installed,& once for material only.  per line in the list.
    'all settings in the list must be filled out regardless of the option is activated.
    Dim StartTime As Double 'this is a timer to see the full duration of the run
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String
    StartTime = Timer

    ' defining the work sheetsa we will use between the data sources.
    ' all data sources are contained in one work book
    Dim wsBM As Worksheet, wsAL As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Set wsAL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto_List")
    Set wsBM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings")
    Set wsSS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shed Settings")

   'Last row number in column A - looking for the end of the list
   lastRow = wsAL.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

   'performs the loop - enter the copy past methods for each cell you need copied and pasted here 
   below 
   this loop
    For i = 2 To lastRow

   'Need to update this from top line transfer to cell to cell direct transfer.
    wsAL.range("A3:AI3").offset(i - 2).Copy
    wsBM.range("A1:AI1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("A3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("B54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("B3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("D54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("C3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("F54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("D3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("H54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("E3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("H58").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("F3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T79").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("G3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T81").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("H3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T83").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("I3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T85").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("J3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("D134").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("K3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("D136").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("L3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("L1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("M3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("M1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("N3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("N1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("O3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("O1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("P3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z118").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("Q3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z120").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("R3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z122").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("S3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z124").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("T3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("b5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("U3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("V3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("W3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("G9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("X3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("AA9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("Y3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D26").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("Z3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AA3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D30").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AB3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("B35").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AC3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("C39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AD3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("E39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AE3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("G39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AF3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("AA39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AG3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D56").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AH3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D58").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AI3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D60").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        
        
                ' Refresh Macro
                ' Refreshes Pivots
                ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
                
  'this section of code then returns the price and sq/cuft data to auto list for iinstalled
  'need to adjust the origin and destination locations to the updated formats in Barnmaster and 
  Autolist
  wsBM.range("AJ1:AN1").Copy
  wsAL.range("AJ3:AN3").offset(i - 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 
  Next i
  
 'this section of code is where we turn off a dropdown for installed
  wsBM.range("U33").Value = "No"
 
 'this section of code then repeats the copy above and reruns the settings
 'from the list to barn master to price and return data for material only
    For i = 2 To lastRow

    
    wsAL.range("A3:AI3").offset(i - 2).Copy
    wsBM.range("A1:AI1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("A3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("B54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("B3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("D54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("C3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("F54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("D3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("H54").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("E3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("H58").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("F3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T79").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("G3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T81").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("H3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T83").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("I3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("T85").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("J3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("D134").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("K3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("D136").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("L3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("L1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("M3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("M1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("N3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("N1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("O3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("O1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("P3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z118").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("Q3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z120").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("R3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z122").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("S3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsBM.range("Z124").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("T3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("b5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("U3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("V3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("W3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("G9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("X3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("AA9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("Y3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D26").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("Z3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AA3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D30").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AB3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("B35").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AC3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("C39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AD3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("E39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AE3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("G39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AF3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("AA39").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AG3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D56").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AH3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D58").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsAL.range("AI3").offset(i - 2).Copy
        wsSS.range("D60").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
                ' Refresh Macro
                ' Refreshes Pivots
                ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
  'this section of code then returns the price and sq/cuft data to auto list for material only
  wsBM.range("AO1:AQ1").Copy
  wsAL.range("AO3:AQ3").offset(i - 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  
  Next i
  
 'this section of code is where we turn on a dropdown for for the next ideration
 wsBM.range("U33").Value = "YES"
 

'Row Count For MSGBOX Reporting
Dim count As Integer
Dim count1 As Integer
Worksheets("Auto_List").Select
Dim LR As Long, r As Long
count = 0
LR = range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
For r = LR To 2 Step -1
If range("O" & r).Value = "Not RTV" Then
count = count + 1

End If
Next r
Dim L As Long, j As Long
count1 = 0
LT = range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
For j = LT To 2 Step -1
If Not range("O" & j).Value = " " Then
count1 = count1 + 1

End If
Next j
Worksheets("Auto_List").Select
    
'Determine how many seconds code took to run
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
'Notify user in seconds
MsgBox count1 & " Records(s) Updated (2 Passes) " & ", Calculations completed successfully in " & 
MinutesElapsed & " Hours : Minutes : Seconds", vbInformation

 
End Sub***
```

The issue is the auto_list worksheet has 4 rows in it at this moment when it complete there are 5 with the first portion blank and the result that gets copied and pasted back to it as a response for each section id either 0's or div/0 because it is coping blank data from the proceeding columns of the 5th row, however, I cannot find where I have errored that is causing this to read a blank row. the work boor row starts on to 3 columns a and goes to "ai3" with the data needed to perform the calculations, column aj3 to am3 is where it pastes the response for the top section of the code for each iteration then on the second pass it pastes the response to the calculations to column ao3:aq3, at least that what I need it to do the issue is that a7;ai7 is blank and the loop sees it as having data and tries to run the calculations with blank data thus the response it reports back are erroneous. Somewhere I have the last row settings incorrect and I have tried to adjust it but alls I cannot get it configured correctly to produce the desired result. Any help identifying the issue is greatly appreciated. The list is dynamic and the number of rows will change with each use.

Comment: Think we might need to see a sample of data.

Comment: Try loop from 3 to lastrow and change offset to (I - 3). If lastrow is 3 then loop will run once.

Comment: CDP1802 - that was the issue I had to change the "for i =2" to for I =3 but I didn't change all the 2's in the cell to cell transfers! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really see what's wrong without screenshots but here are some suggestions for cutting down your code volume and increasing performance (skipped the counts at the end):

```vba
Sub Autolist_INS_MO()
    
    Dim wsBM As Worksheet, wsAL As Worksheet, wsSS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, r As Long, loopnum As Long, rw As Range
    
    Set wsAL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auto_List")
    Set wsBM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings")
    Set wsSS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shed Settings")

    lastRow = wsAL.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    For loopnum = 1 To 2         'making two passes

        wsBM.Range("U33").Value = IIf(loopnum = 1, "YES", "No") 'set dropdown

        'loop over rows in data
        For Each rw In wsAL.Range("A3:A" & lastRow).EntireRow.Rows
            
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'speed up
            With wsBM
                'Transfer values directly without copy/paste
                .Range("A1:AI1").Value = rw.Columns("A:AI").Value
                .Range("B54").Value = rw.Columns("A").Value
                .Range("D54").Value = rw.Columns("B").Value
                .Range("F54").Value = rw.Columns("C").Value
                'etc etc
            End With
            With wsSS
                .Range("B5").Value = rw.Columns("T").Value
                .Range("C9").Value = rw.Columns("U").Value
                .Range("E9").Value = rw.Columns("V").Value
                'etc etc
            End With
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            
            ' Refresh Macro; Refreshes Pivots
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            
            'copy results back to source row
            If loopnum = 1 Then
                rw.Columns("AJ:AN").Value = wsBM.Range("AJ1:AN1").Value  'pass 1
            Else
                rw.Columns("AO:AQ").Value = wsBM.Range("AO1:AQ1").Value  'pass2
            End If
            
        Next rw
        
    Next loopnum 'next pass of 2 passes
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ERMERGERD!!! Tim, Thank you! that worked amazingly, three records run through it with two passes each, before was 5 minutes 41 seconds - now after adopting your code and adding in the time, it now runs two passes each total time is 41 seconds. thanks again, my mind is blown!